# Woocommerce remove item from cart - PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce, cart

The task is to make a item not purchasable if a customer already bought it.
So my solution was to remove the product if the customer add it in the cart.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'testtt');

function testtt()
{ 
    $token = $_SESSION['******token'];  
    $dataservice = *******Service::getService('DataService');
    $list = $dataservice->getArticleBlacklist( $token );

foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) 
{
    //Get SKU by product_id or if available variation_id
    if( $cart_item['variation_id'] != 0  )
    {
        $prototype = new WC_Product( $cart_item['variation_id'] );      
        $prod_art_id = $prototype->get_sku();   
    }
    else
    {
        $prototype = new WC_Product( $cart_item['product_id'] ) ;       
        $prod_art_id = $prototype->get_sku();   
    }

    //convert SKU from STRING into INTEGER
    $x = intval( $prod_art_id );

    //Remove product
    if( $x == $list->int )
    {       
        WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
    }
    else
    {
        continue;           
    }       
}
```

I tried some different art of code 
 for example:

```
//Remove product
if( $x == $list['int'] )
{
```

And a lot of other things... nothing works. But the thing is that I know it works. Because if I change

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'testtt');
```

into

```
add_action( 'parse_reqeust', 'testtt');
```

the code does what it has to do. I am very confused because I did some days ago a code with the same task and it still works (There I had to remove ALL OTHER products from cart if the 'marked' product was add to cart ).

Info: in $list I am getting the Article SKU from the "blacklisted" product as an

```
 `object {["int"]=>int(*number*)}` .
```

I hope someone could help me. Thanks^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

- It seems that in your code that you have may be forgotten `session_start()` or not?
- to get the product from cart item simply use `$cart_item['data']` *(it also handle product variation)* . To get the product sku use directly `$cart_item['data']->get_sku()`.

So your revisited code should be:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'testtt');
function testtt()
{ 
    session_start(); // <== Missing?

    $token = $_SESSION['******token'];  
    $dataservice = *******Service::getService('DataService');
    $list = $dataservice->getArticleBlacklist( $token );

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) 
    {
        // Get the product SKU (even for product variations)
        $sku = $cart_item['data']->get_sku(); 

        // Convert SKU from STRING into INTEGER
        $inst_sku = intval( $sku );

        // Remove product
        if( $inst_sku == $list->int )
        {       
            WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
        }
        else
        {
            continue;           
        }       
    }
}
```

But why instead you don't use `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` hook, instead of removing products from cart… Try this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'check_add_to_cart', 20, 3 );
function check_add_to_cart ( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ){
    session_start();

    $token = $_SESSION['******token'];  
    $dataservice = *******Service::getService('DataService');
    $list = $dataservice->getArticleBlacklist( $token );

    // Get sku from the product ID
    $sku = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_sku', true )

    // Convert SKU from STRING into INTEGER
    $int_sku = intval( $sku );

    // If the product is black listed
    if( $int_sku == $list->int )
        // Add a custom error notice and avoid add to cart
        wc_add_notice( __('This product has already been bought... Try something else', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        $passed = false;
    }
    return $passed;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Sorry for such a late response I got some problems at work but thank you very much! You helped me a lot!